# Does Postgres provide a command to flush buffer cache?

Tags: caching, buffer, flush, pg

Hi
   Sometimes I need to do some SQL tuning task, I usually do such tests on my test db.
After I excute a sql statments, I want to flush the buffer cache which containing SQL
statements and sql result, just like the command in Oracle "Alter system flush buffer_cache"
Is PG server provide a commond of this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [See and clear Postgres caches/buffers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216660/see-and-clear-postgres-caches-buffers)

Answer (score 3):

If you're developing on OSX (I haven't tested on linux), you can use `purge` command to force disk cache to be purged (flushed and emptied). Then run your SQL query again and it should execute as if it were the first time.