# Good indexes for queries with projections and products (postgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

What would a good index be for these 2 cases?

A)

```
SELECT p.content, u.name
FROM posts p, admins a, users u
WHERE
p.tag = a.tag and 
a.id = u.id and 
p.content = 'Hello World';
```

B)

```
SELECT u.name, p.date
FROM users u, posts p
WHERE
u.userid = p.userid and 
p.content = 'Hello World';
```

I tried finding out how the performance is affected by creating different indexes one-by-one. With every new index, the query run faster, but then after dropping them, the gained performance remained. So in the end, I couldn't compare.

Comment: Tip of today: switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax - easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Databases cache data and statistics, etc, to memory.  This may be useful to you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216660/see-and-clear-postgres-caches-buffers

Comment: To back up @jarlh : `JOIN` notation is now over 25 years old, it's old enough to vote, drive, even get married, etc.  Not to mention that the older `,` based notation is deprecated in most RDBMS.

Comment: @MatBailie: as much as I agree with you,  I don't think the old implicit joins in the where clause are deprecated in any DBMS. In fact, they _have_ to support them because it's still part of the SQL standard. Some DBMS have deprecated their non-standard syntax for _outer_ joins in the where clause though

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : If being in the ANSI SQL Standards meant that an RDBMS implemented something, life would be a lot simpler.  There is nothing that correlates `still part of the SQL standard` with `have to support them` ;)

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

So, write the queries like this:

```
SELECT p.content, u.name
FROM posts p JOIN
     admins a
     ON p.tag = a.tag JOIN
     users u
     ON a.id = u.id
WHERE p.content = 'Hello World';
```

And:

```
SELECT u.name, p.date
FROM posts p JOIN
     users u
     ON u.userid = p.userid
WHERE p.content = 'Hello World';
```

The best indexes are on

- `posts(content, tag)`
- `admins(tag, id)`
- `users(id, name)`
- `posts(content, userid, date)`
- `users(userid, name)`

Unfortunately, there is not a single index for each table that matches these queries.  They are using different columns.

Comment: The order of the columns within these indices plays a significant role in this case?


Also, assuming that the "WHERE p.content = 'Hello World';" was always fixed, wouldn't it be even better to use it somehow for partial indexing?

Comment: @Gouz . . . The order of columns in an index is very important.

Comment: Would different (relatively) table sizes, prefer Multi-Column Indexes of different column order? For example in case A: Should the indexing order remain the same among the following 2 cases?: 1) I expect users<posts<admins and 2) I expect admins<users<posts.

Why I ask: The DBMS should better use the smallest table for the inner loop, right? Could my indexes help there somehow?

Comment: @Gouz . . . Under most circumstances, these would be the best indexes for the query, because the index would be used directly for the `where` clause.